# How to add order by on Custom field on query_posts

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
 query_posts(array(
               'post_category' => 'xyz',
               'post_type' => 'abc',
               'posts_per_page' =>'16',
               'paged'=> $paged,
               'orderby' => 'post_title',
               'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

I want to order the records being fetched based on the title of the post in ascending order.
When i print the result using

```
echo 'query : '.$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;
```

I notice that the order by field is post_date

I have pasted the query below:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (7) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'abc' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 16
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with `get_posts()`:

```
$args = array(
  'category' => 'xyz',
  'post_type' => 'abc',
  'posts_per_page' =>16,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC' 
);

$myposts=get_posts($args);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($myposts as $post){ setup_postdata( $post );
  echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();?>
echo '</ul>';
```

But I'm not sure what `'paged'=> $paged,` is.

Comment: Pagination doesn't work as straight forward with `get_posts` as with `WP_Query`. The `paged` parameter is used for pagination of the query and should always be set if you need pagination. But as I said, if you need a paginated custon query, use `WP_Query`, `get_posts` is (extremely for me) difficult to paginate. Only use `get_posts` on non paginated queries

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because you did not use `query_posts`. You are correct to recommend anything else than `query_posts`

Comment: Aha. Thanks. I'd add the offset. something like this: `'offset'=>(16*$current_page)-16`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this, it should be:

```
query_posts(array(
  'post_category' => 'xyz',
  'post_type' => 'abc',
  'posts_per_page' =>'16',
  'paged'=> $paged,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Comment: NO! **NEVER** use `query_posts` never. Use `WP_Query`